# How to add loop counter to foreach in csh

Tags: loops, foreach, counter, csh

In CSH foreach loop or for loop, how can I add a loop iterator or counter which increases from 10 to 1000 with steps of 20?

Something like `foreach i (1..20..5)` or `for (i=1;i<20;i++)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have the `seq` command, you can use:

```
foreach i (`seq 1 5 20`)
  ... body ...
end
```

If you don't have `seq`, here is a version based on @csj's answer:

```
@ i = 1
while ($i <= 20)
  ... body ...
  @ i += 5
end
```

Comment: Or, for BSD and OS X: `jot - 1 20 5`

Answer (score 2):

Any documentation I've found online seems to indictate no for loop is available. However, the while loop can be used. I don't actually know csh, so the following is approximate based on what I read:

```
set i = 10
while ($i <= 1000)
    # commands...
    set i = $i + 20
end
```

Comment: Actually, it'd be `@ i = 1` and `@ i = $i + 1`

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the syntax correction. As for the values, the question  requests a counter that goes from 10 to 1000 in steps of 20. Thus, an initial value of 10, and + 20 each time through the loop.

Comment: The csh for loop is called with foreach. In fact, if you type "csh for" in the google search box, it shows foreach as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use expr. the following worked for me (in tcsh but csh should be the same):

```
% set n=0
% foreach x (`ls $A*`)
foreach? set n=`expr $n + 1`
foreach? echo $n
foreach? end
```

output is
    1
    2
    3
    4
etc